# (Win Server 2019) Slow Read/Write network shared files using SMB protocol

Tags: windows, active-directory, network-share, windows-server-2019

I have a running Windows Server 2019 used as a File Server.
He is having a problem: When reading/writing files via network share (SMB Protocol) the request takes a long time to complete...

This is happening on Office 97-2003 files, PDFs, Solid Works archives, and some other extensions.

Things i tested:

1. HARDWARE - HD, NIC, CPU, Memory. All returned good and positive results... No phisical problems
2. Network: Internal connection and external is OK. Low latency. No loss.
3. Tried accessing those files LOCALLY only - Problem didnt occur.
4. Created the SAME structure using ANOTHER server on the same network - Same OS (Win SRV 2019) with even the SAME BUILD! Problem DIDNT happen.

So, basically this problem is just happening on that specific server. I have no idea on what to do

Does anyone went through this and can give me a little help? A light on the end of the tunnel ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer, and the problem appears to be rather unpredictable, but after some research a while back I found this solution and it does appear to work.

On the client computer perform the following - **AT YOUR OWN RISK**:

In an elevated Powershell prompt run the following command: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "SMB1Protocol-Client" -All`

Add the registry value **ProviderFlags** as a REG_DWORD with a value of 1 to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\**Drive Letter**` for all mapped drives (where **Drive Letter** is a registry entry for each mapped drive..

Comment: Wouldn't it be prudent to include a caveat that this is contrary to best practices and significantly reduces the security posture of the client?

Comment: I suppose. I've always assumed that people evaluate the risks for themselves. I don't take anything I read on the interwebs as gospel.

Comment: With all of the inexperienced people who read and participate in this site, I suspect that most people don't evaluate the risks because they don't even know what they are.